# Android Permissions not Working

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am creating a very simple text program, but when i send a text I keep getting the error java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10057 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

As far as I can see I am using the correct syntax to ask permission and I am putting the request in the correct place in the manifest.

Here are screenshots of my problem:
http://puu.sh/kV0IX/d21a43281f.png
http://puu.sh/kV0P2/c7355a5eab.png